# Visualization of sensor values in Windows Forms using 3d objects programmed with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, 3d, data-visualization

I get sensor values through UART, which I want to log and visualize in a windows form application programmed in C#. For the visualization I would like to use 3D objects that were created in Blender. How can I integrate the 3D speedometer object in the windows form and animate the needle using the sensor value?

In the end it shoud look like this (here it is an image I pasted):
[image]

Comment: If somebody is looking for a speedometer / clock library for winforms you are welcome to visit my Business-Clocks-Charts project in GitHub: https://github.com/Jonathan435/Business-Clocks-Charts.